# Discord.js "TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm doing a bot in discord, I was trying to do a kick command, but every time I execute the command, in the terminal it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined"

Kick script:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member",
    execute(message, args){
        if(message.member.permission.has("KICK_MEMBERS")){
            const member = message.mentions.users.first();
            if(member){
                const memberTarger = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
                memberTarger.kick();
                message.channel.send('User has been kicked');
            }else{
                message.channel.send('You couldnt kick this member');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main script:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client();
const prefix = '$';
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'clear'){
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'kick'){
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's a typo. It should be `permissions`, not `permission`. Try `message.member.permissions.has` https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#checking-member-permissions) it's : `member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')`